# A problem about class equation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $k$ be a finite field, where $|k|=q$ and $\operatorname{char}k\neq2$, and let
$$D=\{A\in\operatorname{SL}(2,k)\mid A \text{ is diagonalizable}\}.$$
Prove that $$|D|=2+\tfrac{1}{2}\cdot(q+1)\cdot q\cdot(q-3).$$
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Can you express $|\operatorname{SL}(2,k)|$ in terms of $q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We know that $|GL(2,k)| = (q^2-1)(q^2-q)$, and $|k^{\ast}| = (q-1)$, so
   $$
   |SL(2,k)| = (q+1)(q^2-q)
   $$
2. Now, consider
   $$
   \hat{D} := \left\lbrace A_{\lambda} := \begin{pmatrix}
   \lambda & 0 \\
   0 & \lambda^{-1}
   \end{pmatrix} : \lambda \in k^{\ast} \right\rbrace
   $$
   and consider the conjugacy class $C(A_{\lambda})$ of $A_{\lambda}$.

a) If $\lambda =1$ or $\lambda = -1$ (which are different since $2\neq 0$), $A_{\lambda}$ is in the center of $SL(2,k)$, and so
$$
|C(A_1)| = 1 = |C(A_{-1})|
$$
b) For any other $\lambda \in k^{\ast}$, the centralizer of $A_{\lambda}$ is precisely $\hat{D}$, which has cardinality $|k^{\ast}| = (q-1)$. By the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem,
$$
|C(A_{\lambda})| = \frac{|SL(2,k)|}{|\hat{D}|} = q(q+1)
$$
Each such $\lambda$ occurs in pairs $\{\lambda, \lambda^{-1}\}$, and there are
$$
\frac{1}{2}(q-3)
$$
such pairs (everything in $k$ excluding $\{0,1,-1\}$). Hence,
$$
|D| = 2 + \frac{1}{2}(q-3)q(q+1)
$$

Comment: It seems to be the right solution. Thank you so much!